# Show modal modal message on form success

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I have a custom form that submits via AJAX. On form error, i simply return the whole form on my callback function, and the HTML is replaced, but i want it to open a modal dialog on success. What is the best way to do this? This is what i'm currently doing (i don't like this solution because i can't clear the form values, among other things):

```
    public function ajaxCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

        drupal_get_messages(); // Hide the status messages

        $form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);

        if ($errors = $form_state->getErrors()) {

          return $form;
        }
        else {

          $response = new AjaxResponse();

          $title = 'Consectetur adipiscing elit';
          $text  = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.';

          $response->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand($title, $text));

          return $response;
        }
      }
```

Comment: I did something very similar in a similar scenario.

Comment: Note that if you want to add the error messages to the AJAX form, you can just add the `messages` element to the start of the form.

Comment: What would really be perfect form me would be able to always return ajax commands. The problem is if i simply return $response->addCommand(new Command('#my-form-wrapper', drupal_render($form))); the form gets broken. the only way for ajax to keep functioning is returning the whole form, or not touching it at all.

Comment: When you return the form array, drupal converts it to AJAX commands, so technically you can write those commands yourself, though i don't recommend it.

Comment: Yes, i'm trying to do that and i keep breaking ajax functionality.

Comment: You don't need to `render` the form and return it.

Comment: I need to, because i'm doing changes to the HTML.

Comment: @JoséTrindade, this is exactly the opposite, you should not render early, because ajax commands which add html have a method to render and at the same time preserve the attachments most ajax forms need.

Comment: @4k4 So i should add a command like this: $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#my-form-wrapper', $form)); instead of render?

Comment: yes, but you might need to use HtmlCommand()

Comment: I'm adding a wrapper to the form: 
        $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="my-form-wrapper">';
        $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i came up with (many thanks to @4k4):

```
    public function ajaxCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

        drupal_get_messages(); // Hide messages

        $form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);

        if ($errors = $form_state->getErrors()) {

           return $form; // Simply Return the form
        }
        else {

         $response = new AjaxResponse();

         $title = 'Consectetur adipiscing elit';
         $text  = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.';

        $response->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand($title, $text));

        // Or add the $form as parameter to an HTML command.
        $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#my-form-wrapper', $form)); 

        // Do notice i added a wrapper to my form in the buildForm() method:
        // $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="my-form-wrapper">';
        // $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

         return $response;
    }
```